# A Poisson process game

Tags: probability, markov-chains, poisson-process

An interesting puzzle I came across:

> For $T>1$, observe a Poisson process of rate $1$ on the time interval $(0,T)$. Every time we observe a point, we may choose to stop. To win the game, we must stop on the last point before time $T$. Else, if we stop at $t$ and there is another point in $(t,T)$, we lose. Also, if we never stop, we also lose. What is the best strategy for playing this game?

My hypothesis is that we should stop as close to $\lfloor T\rfloor$ as possible each time to maximise our chances of winning, but a proof is more difficult to come up with. Can you prove my claim correct?

Comment: Do you have to chose when to stop at $t=0$ or can you chose to stop depending on how the process runs ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom each time a point is observed, we are given the opportunity to stop at that point. Like blackjack—you are given a card, you observe, then have the opportunity to stick or hit.

Comment: Stop at the first point after $T-1$. Your claim can't be true as there is nothing special about integer $T$.

Comment: @A.S. okay, I see where you're coming from. Care to elaborate on why $T-1$ is the solution, then?

Comment: If you stop at time $t$ away from the end,  you win with probability $e^{-t}$. If you continue instead - deciding to stop at the first point after that time - you win with probability $\int_0^t e^{-x}e^{-(t-x)}\,dx=te^{-t}$. Hence it make sense to continue as long as $t>1$.

Comment: This also yields probability of winning the game: $e^{-1}$.

Comment: @A.S.: I think that series of comments constitutes an answer.